# background-position css not working with a variable

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to set a background position from the parent. If I put the pixel number, it works but doesn't work with a variable.

```
   $('.bg-img').css('background-position', '250px 50%');
```

The above is working.

```
 var x = $(div).position();
 var posX;

 posX = parseInt(x.left);
 $('.bg-img').css("background-position", "'" + posX + "px 50%'");
```

This is not working. Is the syntax wrong here?

Comment: Your first line is: `"250px 50%"` the second is `"'250px 50%'"` - why did you add the extra `'`?

Comment: Yes, that was wrong. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it like:

```
 $('.bg-img').css("background-position", posX + "px 50%");
```

it´s just a string, no weird double / single quote mixing necesasry

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `"'"` while concatenating you can do like this

```
 posX = parseInt(x.left);

 tempPos =  posX + "px 50%";

$('.bg-img').css("background-position", tempPos);

// or simply as john suggested

 $('.bg-img').css("background-position", posX + "px 50%");
```